# Search firebase database for key and check if it contains expected value

Tags: android, firebase

I want to use the user id of the user object to check if the role value is equal to employee, but I am not sure how to do that. I know how to get the user id but the rest i am unaware of. My database looks like this:

```
-User
   -userid
      firstName:John
      lastName:Wall
      role:Employee
   - userid
      firstName:Bradley
      lastName:Beal
      role:Patient
```

Comment: Did you try the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a query:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
ref.orderByChild("role").equalTo("Employee").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             String name = ds.child("firstName").getValue(String.class);
         }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

First add reference to node `User` then use `orderByChild()` to retrieve the name of the users that have role equal to Employee.